# Quickbooks SDK Call Limitations

Tags: c#, sdk, quickbooks

I am using the CustomerAdd demo program in QuickBooks SDK to add customers. When I add a customer, I can set the name plus two other fields (i.e., phone and email) but if I try to set more than 2, I get the error "QuickBooks found an error when parsing the XML input stream." Is this a limitation on a trial version or something? My version of Quickbooks is a trial version.

Comment: You should post your code/XML. How can we help you if we can't see what you're doing?

Answer (score 2):

Answer shamelessly ripped from this [qbXML wiki article at consolibyte.com](http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/QbXML_FAQ):

**What does "0x80040400 QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream." mean?**

It means you have some sort of strange error in your qbXML request. Try running the your qbXML request through the QuickBooks qbXML test/validator utilities included in the QuickBooks SDK.

It's worth noting that order matters when building qbXML requests. For example, if the qbXML request is defined in the OSR like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="7.0"?>
<QBXML>
  <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
    <CustomerAddRq>
      <CustomerAdd>
        <Name>STRTYPE</Name>
        <FirstName>STRTYPE</FirstName>
        <MiddleName>STRTYPE</MiddleName>
        <LastName>STRTYPE</LastName>
        ...
```

Then this will not work (because the `<Name>…</Name>` and `<FirstName>…</FirstName>` tags are in the opposite order):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="7.0"?>
<QBXML>
  <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
    <CustomerAddRq>
      <CustomerAdd>
        <FirstName>Keith</FirstName>        
        <Name>Keith R Palmer</Name>
        <MiddleName>R</MiddleName>
        <LastName>Palmer</LastName>
        ...
```

Other common errors would include:

- Leaving out required elements
- Forgetting to close tags/really ugly, invalid XML streams
- Sending non-ASCII or non-UTF-8 text (don't send strange, non-standard characters)
- Sending XML attributes that should be escaped: & < >. These need to be converted to: & < > to include them in qbXML requests.
- Using a version of qbXML that your version of QuickBooks does not support
- Using a node that your version of qbXML does not support

**How can I troubleshoot qbXML errors?**

- Use the "XML Validator" tool included with the QuickBooks SDK. You can feed it an XML document, and it will tell you more or less exactly where the errors are.
- Compare your XML (especially the order of the XML nodes) against the OSR: https://member.developer.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html

Comment: +1 for running the xml through the validator; this has saved me a ton of heartache.  The ordering of the nodes is specific.